# Web: Can drag (ontouchmove) only a little on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I try to implement a horizontal drag and drop. It works fine on desktop, but I can only drag it a little on mobile device before the whole page scrolls horizontally. How to solve it?

(You can use the mobile inspector in the browser. Please drag the db to trash)

```js
let endX;
(() => {
  const [db, trash] = [document.querySelector('#refresh span:first-of-type'), document.querySelector('#refresh span:last-of-type')];
  db.onpointerdown = pressed => {
    db.style.transition = null;
    document.onpointermove = document.ontouchmove = moving => {
      moving.preventDefault();
      endX = moving.targetTouches?.[0].pageX;
      db.style.transform = `translateX(${(moving.clientX || endX) - pressed.clientX}px)`;
      trash.style.color = (moving.clientX || endX) > trash.getBoundingClientRect().x ? 'lime' : null;
    }
  }
  document.onpointerup = document.ontouchend = lifted => {
    if (document.onpointermove == null)
      return;
    if ((lifted.clientX || endX) > trash.getBoundingClientRect().x)
      document.querySelector('h6').innerText = 'good!';
    db.style.transform = null;
    db.style.transition = 'transform .5s';
    document.onpointermove = document.ontouchmove = null;
  }
})();
```

```css
:root {
  text-align: right;
}

#refresh div {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#refresh span:first-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}

#refresh h6 {
  margin: 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id=refresh>
  <div>
    <span>db</span>
    <h6>........................</h6>
    <span>trash</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: On an iPad I can drag db to trash with no problem. Does the problem occur on other real devices?

Comment: Yes, like Surface Go